# Excel Countif in R - Add new column keeping original number of rows

Tags: r, countif

I need to add a new column to my dataset, which counts the frequencies of observations in an existing column. So, if an observation occurs two times, I need that new column to give me a 2 twice, next to each occurrence.

Orig Dataset

```
Col 1  
a
a
b
c
c
c
```

New Dataset

```
Col 1    Col 2
a        2
a        2
b        1
c        3
c        3
c        3
```

Comment: can you copy your output into the question rather than uploading screen shots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the `dplyr` package. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(`Col 1`) %>%
  mutate(`Col 2` = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  count(`Col 1`) %>%
  left_join(dat, ., by = "Col 1") %>%
  rename(`Col 2` = n)
```

Or use the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)

dat2 <- dat[, "Col 2" := .N, by = "Col 1"]
```

Or the base R

```
dat2 <- merge(dat, as.data.frame(table(dat$`Col 1`)), by.x = "Col 1", by.y = "Var1")
names(dat2) <- c("Col 1", "Col 2")
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "'Col 1'  
a
                  a
                  b
                  c
                  c
                  c",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(dat) <- "Col 1"
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the speed and cleaner output of the package solutions, I like the base R solution because it's more intuitive, at least for me.

Comment: @gm0203 Glad to help. Please accept this post as the answer if this solves your question.

Comment: @gm0203 If you don't know how to accept an answer, please see this link (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)